# Glitching when dragging

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2

I have a very simple code for drag and drop in `qml`.

But when you are dragging the rectangle while holding mouse the screen of window is glitched! and sometimes the color of some `Rectangle` vanishes.

Like this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-94929) is reported, but not answered.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQml.Models 2.1


Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 700
    height: 800
    visible: true

    color: 'grey'

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
    GridView {
        id: root
        width: 320; height: 480
        cellWidth: 80; cellHeight: 80
        pixelAligned: true

        displaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad }
        }

        model: DelegateModel {
            id: visualModel
            model: ListModel {
                id: colorModel
                ListElement { color: "blue" }
                ListElement { color: "green" }
                ListElement { color: "red" }
                ListElement { color: "yellow" }
                ListElement { color: "orange" }
                ListElement { color: "purple" }
                ListElement { color: "cyan" }
                ListElement { color: "magenta" }
                ListElement { color: "chartreuse" }
                ListElement { color: "aquamarine" }
                ListElement { color: "indigo" }
                ListElement { color: "black" }
                ListElement { color: "lightsteelblue" }
                ListElement { color: "violet" }
                ListElement { color: "grey" }
                ListElement { color: "springgreen" }
                ListElement { color: "salmon" }
                ListElement { color: "blanchedalmond" }
                ListElement { color: "forestgreen" }
                ListElement { color: "pink" }
                ListElement { color: "navy" }
                ListElement { color: "goldenrod" }
                ListElement { color: "crimson" }
                ListElement { color: "teal" }
            }
            delegate: DropArea {
                id: delegateRoot

                width: 80; height: 80

                onEntered: visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, icon.visualIndex)
                property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex
                Binding { target: icon; property: "visualIndex"; value: visualIndex }

                Rectangle {
                    id: icon
                    property int visualIndex: 0
                    width: 72; height: 72
                    anchors {
                        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
                        verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    radius: 3
                    color: model.color

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        color: "white"
                        text: parent.visualIndex
                    }

                    DragHandler {
                        id: dragHandler
                    }

                    Drag.active: dragHandler.active
                    Drag.source: icon
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: 36
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: 36

                    states: [
                        State {
                            when: icon.Drag.active
                            ParentChange {
                                target: icon
                                parent: root
                            }

                            AnchorChanges {
                                target: icon
                                anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}

}
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After drag]

Comment: what is your Qt Version and OS? Do you have a graphic card? I test it but I didn't see problem It works good for me

Comment: I would not recommend making changes to the source model during `DragArea.onEntered`. This probably would make things glitch because it's changing the model whilst the component is being rendered. Rather, I would update the model when the dragging is complete, i.e. consider moving the code to either `DragArea.onDropped` or `DragArea.onPositionChanged`?

Comment: Try changing the render backend or removing the border radius and see the effects.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Windows 11,  Qt Creator 4.11.1, Built on Feb 5 2020, 3050 ti nvidia Laptop.

Comment: @StephenQuan, I saw it in example of Qt itself.

Comment: Okay, what happens if you rewrite the `DragArea.onEntered` to `onEntered: Qt.callLater(visualModel.items.move, drag.source.visualIndex, icon.visualIndex)` - i.e. try to put a minimal time delay?

Comment: @StephenQuan Nothing.

Comment: Can I change graphic card for compile with open-gl? cause use my intel graphic card!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With add [attribute of open-gl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) in `main.cpp`

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
```

Answer (score 1):

@SAt looks like you found the issue with your rendering engine. Sometimes there are quirks like that in your graphics card and may require updating your graphics driver. Otherwise, as you found, see the other rendering options with `QCoreApplication::setAttribute()` or by setting the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable:

- `Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL` Equivalent to setting `QT_OPENGL` to `desktop`.
- `Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES` Equivalent to setting `QT_OPENGL` to `angle`.
- `Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL` Equivalent to setting `QT_OPENGL` to `software`.

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#setAttribute
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers

Comment: thx, only with `AA_UseDesktopOpenGL` my problem still exists. And with `AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL` it is consumed by CPU and GPU, but with `AA_UseOpenGLES` only use GPU. And it's better these files exist in root folder of `.exe`: `libegl.dll, libglesv2.dll, d3dcompiler.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code in my system and it works well.

My **OS** is `Ubuntu 20.04`.

My **Qt Version** is `5.15.2` and `6.2.3` I checked in both.

**This is the Result:**

[image]

Comment: I tested on a PC with a lower graphics card (Win 10-Qt5.14 & win 11-Qt5.15.2), that had nice result. But in my laptop with any Qt ver, the same problem exists. and in `Application Output`, showed many message of `qt.scenegraph.general`.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43296, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55162?focusedCommentId=327778&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel.